# How to add the same song to Deezer Queue multiple times?

Tags: deezer

I am developing a Deezer Web Player here http://deezer.gopagoda.com, but I am facing the problem that I don't know how to add the same song multiple times to list with the DZ.player.addToQueue method... Every time I add a song, I print the Queue Object and I get the song only once!!

Answer (score 0):

I know that's not the best way, but you could use DZ.playTracks with several times the same track id. I'd agree with you that you wouldn't be able to dynamically change the queue, but I don't see any other solution for now.